# Is the dominating 7-set problem known to be solvable in ​ n$^{7+\hspace{.03 in}o(1)}$ ​ time?

Tags: paper-review

[This paper](http://stanford.edu/~rrwill/cnf-sat-feasible.pdf) says "For k ≥ 7, k-Dominating Set can be solved in n<sup>k+o(1)</sup> time.",

but [Reference 17](http://people.idsia.ch/~grandoni/Pubblicazioni/EG04tcs.pdf) only makes that claim for ​ ℓ ≥ 8 , ​ and it seems like on the

"Proposition 2" page, the matrices would actually have height ​ $\binom{n}{\hspace{-0.02 in}\lceil k/2\rceil \hspace{.02 in}}$ ​ and ​ $\binom{n}{\hspace{-0.02 in}\lfloor k/2\rfloor \hspace{.02 in}}$ .

(I asked Ryan Williams about this 3 days ago and he hasn't responded yet.)

Comment: If the obvious bound you get from applying the fastest known rectangular matrix multiplication alg (currently LeGall's) doesn't yield the result, then it's a typo/mistake.